# Detecting non working accelerometer, gyroscope or geomagnetic sensor

Tags: android, android-sensors

I'd like to check if one or more of the previous sensors is not working or not existent in a certain mobile phone.

I think that if the result 0,0,0 is obtained from any of these sensors when retrieving it, it means that it's not working but I'm not 100 % sure about that.

Which is a way to check this properly?